# Why would a new washer indicate inadequate water flow after a month of use?

Tags: plumbing, water, appliances, water-pressure, washing-machine

LG replaced my brand new washing machine and after a month this new one is doing the exact same thing - generating error code `IE` (water flow inadequate).

The washer I chose is significantly larger than my previous machine that I only had minor wear and tear with it also was an LG.

Is it possible that my plumbing is not significant to handle the water flow? If this could be the problem, why would it work fine for a month?

Comment: I would turn off the shut off valves and check the filters on the water lines.  If the filters clog up, that will reduce water flow and is usually the cheapest to check and clean.

Comment: Is your water hard? Do you have a softener? is it working? Mineral build-up is one of several possible explanations. Are you on a well system or city/town/public water supply? Do you have a pressure reducing valve? what's it set to or what is your water pressure in the house? Does that change significantly when you run water in general or the washer in specific?

Comment: Have you been through the LG troubleshooting steps already? https://www.lg.com/levant_en/support/product-help/CT20158023-20153085464485 Crip659 also made a good point.

Comment: Do you have good flow in other sinks/tubs?  If so then water flow probably not the problem, but blockage in pipes to the washer, shut off valves not open completely, clogged filters.

Comment: Also check that the shutoff valves are fully on?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause:

There's a sensor and hose that uses air pressure to determine when the machine has been filled with enough water. If that line or sensor is damaged (mine had a rat chew a hole in the rubber hose), it'll fail to detect the water level and report inadequate water level.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer about a rodent is a possible cause.
You should still be under manufac. warranty with it being just purchased.

An LG authorized tech would do this (suggested below) for you, and they could re-calibrate the control to clear the error too if that persists.

Look at your supply lines, and the screens on the water inlet valves. Sometimes these can get debris on them, restricting the water flow, and give this error code. Clean the screen, then run some water down your drain pipe from your inlet line just to give it a flush. Re-attach your hoses, then test the washer.